# Auth(guard )function is not working in laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5.6

I made multiple two different authentications for (users, clients) users is default one and I maintain that for my admin. users default one is working but I try to login with my frontend it's not working always returning this code (`return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email'));`) I can't understand where I making the mistake. Please help me to fix this issue.

I attached my code.

**Auth.php**

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'client' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'clients',
        ],

        'client-api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'clients',
        ],
    ],

'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        'clients' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\client::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],

        'clients' => [
            'provider' => 'clients',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],
```

**Web.php**

```
Route::namespace('Frontend')->group(function (){
    Route::get('/client_login','ClientLoginController@showLogin')->name('Client_Login');
    Route::post('/client_login','ClientLoginController@login')->name('Client_Login.submit');
});
```

**client.php (model)**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;


class client extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $guard = 'client';

    protected $table='clients';

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

**ClientLoginController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Frontend;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;


class ClientLoginController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest:client');
    }


    public function showLogin()
    {
        return view('client_login');
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {

        if(Auth::guard('client')->attempt(['email'=>$request->email,'password'=>Hash::make($request->password)],$request->remember))
        {
            return redirect()->intended(route('FrontClient.index'));
        }

        return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email'));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You pass the **plain** text password to `attempt` **not** the hashed value. You can't do an exact comparison on hashes, they change. You can only do a "hash check" on them.

```
->attempt(['email' => ..., 'password' => $request->input('password')], ...)
```

An example illustrating why you can't directly compare hashes:

```
$one = bcrypt('test');
// "$2y$10$ZJrZ9av0Uc3dcygOmkpsZ.PjdmUHXojLu.NmI2EnpNS5mpBBX5JvO"

$two = bcrypt('test');
// "$2y$10$0R0phwLB.6T6oQkj5XcvPetQntUxmjivR4ddiEdGPQ4cW0M2fES8C"

$one != $two;  // true
```

Comment: Auth::guard('client')->attempt(['email'=>$request->email,'password'=>Hash::make($request->password)],$request->remember) I try this also but not working

Comment: well you didn't read the answer .. you do **not** pass the hashed version of the password, you pass the **plain** text version to `attempt`  :)

Comment: Auth::guard('client')->attempt(['email'=>$request->email,'password'=>$request->password],$request->remember) like this?

Comment: sure, give it a try :-)

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: i couldn't tell you, its your project ... perhaps you didn't hash the password that is saved in the database correctly

Comment: I found the issue database saved encrypted password I entering password is not matching

I'm inserting like this $client->password = Hash::make($request->password);